# How can I configure answers to be sorted by votes instead of prioritizing the accepted answer?

Tags: feature-request, support, accepted-answer, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepted answer shouldn't be sorted to the top when sorting by Newest or Oldest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/accepted-answer-shouldnt-be-sorted-to-the-top-when-sorting-by-newest-or-oldest)

On more than one occasion I have found myself fooled into missing key information I wanted in cases where the accepted answer was significantly lower voted than the answer with the most votes.

Therefore, I'd like to configure my viewing such that the answers are sorted primarily by votes instead of prioritizing the accepted answer to the top.

Can I configure my account so this is the case or if not, can we get this added as a feature?

Another possibility, is there a way to configure to have the highest votes always come second (if it was not accepted) when I am viewing the site?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't, the accepted answer will always show first when you sort answers by votes (unless it's a self accepted answer, in which case it will only be at the top if it's also the highest voted).

Comment: @Arjan Feel free to steal it ;) I remember an older discussion on this, where a similar feature was declined, I'll be busy looking for it for a while.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accepted answer shouldn't be sorted to the top when sorting by Newest or Oldest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/accepted-answer-shouldnt-be-sorted-to-the-top-when-sorting-by-newest-or-oldest) or [Shouldn't the answer with more votes be above the accepted answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111230/shouldnt-the-answer-with-more-votes-be-above-the-accepted-answer)

Comment: @Arjan, those are similar, but not duplicates in my mind.

Comment: Very well, sorry then. But you did not show any prior research in your question (in which you could have indicated more precisely why your request is different), and I cannot revoke my close vote... (And the highest voted always comes first or second, when sorting by votes...?) Anyway, there's a user script for that: [Modified answer view based only on votes, not accepted status](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60777/modified-answer-view-based-only-on-votes-not-accepted-status).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Yannis above:

Unfortunately you can't, the accepted answer will always show first when you sort answers by votes (unless it's a self accepted answer, in which case it will only be at the top if it's also the highest voted).